# How to start a Small App from an Activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, tablet, sony

I'm developing a Small App for the Xperia™ Tablet S using the Small App SDK from Sony.

Small apps are special miniature apps that run on top of other applications.

My problem is I'm trying to launch a Small App from an Activity to run the Monkey to find possible problems.

I tried launch using the startService(new Intent(this, SmallAppSample.class)) but I have had no success.

Does anyone know a solution for this issue?

Comment: SmallAppSample.class is service or activity ?

Comment: is a SmallApplication that is the base class to implement small apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SmallApplicationManager`

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmallAppSample.class);
    SmallApplicationManager.startApplication(MainActivity.this, i);
```